Formula Name Error converting address list to address block list
6240 Grand Blvd; Grace Church to 6200 Block Grand Blvd.; Grace Church

To convert addresses to block listed addresses I am trying to use this four step formula:
=LEFT(A2,(FIND(" ",A2,1)-1))  
=MID(A2,FIND(" ",A2),200)
=CONCAT(FLOOR(B2,100)," BLOCK",C2)
=CONCAT(FLOOR(LEFT(A2,(FIND(" ",A2,1)-1)),100)," BLOCK",MID(A2,FIND(" ",A2),200))

Step three and four, I am receiving #NAME? error.
